# Can I extend a minor's US passport before its expiry?

Tags: usa, passports, us-citizens, passport-renewals

A US minor's passport still has 2 years remaining, however, is it possible to preemptively extend it, anticipating a foreign relocation?

Comment: There's no need to do that.  You can renew the passport at the US consulate or embassy.

Comment: It is also entirely possible to renew a passport while reading in a foreign country.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may apply for a new passport at any time. [Link](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/apply-renew-passport/under-16.html) The ability to obtain a new passport does not change whether a minor or not. But you may not **renew** a minor's passport.

> All passport applicants under 16 must apply in person using Form DS-11. You can not use Form DS-82 to renew your passport.

Comment: Note that only a US passport issued when the person is 16 or older can be "renewed". Since the title says "minor", there is a good chance the passport was issued before the person was 16, and thus cannot be "renewed"; and they would need to instead apply for a new passport.

Comment: @user102008 duly noted and edited!